# Conflicting Kashrut indications

Tags: kashrut-kosher

A box of Manishewitz dark-chocolate-covered matzah says in the front that OU certified it as parve, but says in the back: "May contain nuts, soy, milk".  Why the disconnect?  Does it mean that the OU inspector did not detect any trace of milk, but the company doesn't want to be liable in case a milk-intolerant user gets sick because the machines may have retained faint traces of previous use for dairy products?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kashrus-and-allergens/

Comment: I suspect it has to do with different standards for cleaning equipment between the governmental regulatory agencies and the kashrus certification agencies. I can't speak to specifics, but I suspect that the legal standards for removing that line are more strict than even hilchos kashrus.